# How to combine modal dialog editor and in-place widget editor in QModelViews?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, delegates

I have a model with simple and complex data and I would like to have in-place widgets to edit simple data, but modal dialogs to edit complex data... How can I achieve that in a clean way?
(I would really prefer to do everything via a sub class of QItemDelegate, and no view specific hack)

Answer (score 4):

I think you have to subclass the view and override the `QAbstractItemView::edit()` function to handle different editing paths. For example:

```
class MyView : public QTreeView
{
    [..]
protected:
    bool edit(const QModelIndex &index, EditTrigger trigger, QEvent *event)
    {
        if (index.row() > 5) { // Use your own criteria for simple/complex data
            // Simple data with default editor.
            return QTreeView::edit(index, trigger, event);
        } else {
            // Edit complex data.
            QDialog dialog;
            dialog.exec();
            return false;
        }
    }
    [..]
};
```

Comment: I don't want to be view-specific as said (the delegate could be given to several views)

Comment: @hl037_, the same sub class could be used for several views too. Use `MyView` when you create a treeview or whatever. The problem with delegate is that you have to provide a widget that will be shown in your view, but it cannot be a modal dialog.

Comment: Just to complete this nice answer: if you decide to override the view's `edit()` member function, do note that some checks that Qt would normally perform in edit() will need to be done manually.

In particular, the edit trigger and index flags need to be checked to make sure that the editor dialog is only shown when the selected item is editable and only according to your configured triggers (e.g. on double click). To do so, just check whether `editTriggers() & trigger` and `index.flags() & (Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable)` are true.

Answer (score 2):

Try next delegate. I show main idea in the example:

Header:

```
#ifndef ITEMDELEGATE_H
#define ITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>

class ItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ItemDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget * editor, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget * editor, QAbstractItemModel * model, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget * editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem & option, const QModelIndex & index) const;
    bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // ITEMDELEGATE_H
```

I show you only `editorEvent` because all another methods you can wrote by yourself, it will  be custom delegate, but in `editorEvent` we create modal dialog.

```
bool ItemDelegate::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model,
                               const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                               const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if(index.row()%2)//specific items, you can use it another options, it is just example
    {
        QInputDialog* dia = new QInputDialog;//create dialog, just example, it can be your QDialog subclass        
        dia->setInputMode(QInputDialog::TextInput);
        //dia->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        dia->setModal(true);
        connect(dia, &QInputDialog::finished,[=]()//connection which will take data from dialog
        {
           model->setData(index,dia->textValue());//provide some method in your dialog to get user data and set it in model 
           delete dia;//we don't want memory leaks
         });
        dia->show();
    }
    return QItemDelegate::editorEvent(event,model,option,index);
}
```

I used here `C++11` (`CONFIG += c++11` to `.pro` file) and [new syntax of signals and slots](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: Your solution is not complete, but almost :
I worked on it considering this bug : https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-11908 and this blog entry : https://blogs.kde.org/node/3919 . QItemDelegate::editorEvent has to be called in an else clause because it will provide an editor after the modal dialog, and it will crash the application because of losing the focus (which will destroy the default editor widget... so when accessing again, boom)

Comment: @hl037_ I tested this code, it works as you want, Qt 5.2.0, I start editing, dialog appears I input data, press Ok, and data appears in my model and view.

Comment: As expected : SIGSEGV on Archlinux (kernel Linux 3.17.3-1-ARCH) and Qt 5.3.2 .
It depends of the platform : should work on Windows but crash on Linux and Mac (as explained in the two links I wrote above)

Comment: @hl037_ in this case sorry :(

Comment: no problem ;)
just to add a ```return true;``` in the ```if``` (it is a ```return false``` which cause the error), and to use a QPointer to store dia. and then it should work.
(need to add also a test to check if it's a double click which has rose the event, but this is user specific) ...But this solution is quite dangerous as you experienced, but it seems to be the only which do the trick

Comment: @hl037_ Have you ever figured out a fully reliable approach to open a dialog instead of an inline editor (preferably supported by Qt documentation)? [QTBUG-11908](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11908) warns against opening dialogs in `editorEvent` because it triggers another event loop which is apparently not well handled.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but given that both answers are production-unsatisfactory (crash when returning false, nested event loops, etc)...
Please note I'm not faulting the posters for saying "it can't be done cleanly that way".

How about an entirely different, supported approach?

I have an implementation like this before (pseudo-code):

1. Disable edit triggers for "complex" items

.

```
auto item = model->item(row, column);
item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemFlag::ItemIsEditable); // not editable
```

2. Connect to `QAbstractItemView::activated`

Ignore event for "simple" items

```
connect(m_ui.tableView,
  &QAbstractItemView::activated,
  this,
  &QtGuiApplication2::onDataActivated);

//...

void QtGuiApplication2::onDataActivated(const QModelIndex &index) {
  if(!is_complex)
    return;

  EditDialog dlg;
  if(dlg.exec() == QDialog::DialogCode::Accepted) {
    updatemodel();
  }

}
```

3. Item Delegate:
   Ignore for "complex" items.

   ```
   QWidget* VariableEditorDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent,
   const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
   const QModelIndex &index) const {
     if(is_complex)
       return nullptr; // same as base class
     return new EditorWidget(parent);
   }
   ```

Now of course this isn't as nice as having just the delegate, but at least it doesn't skirt so closesly along crashes.